# Is it possible to style jQuery UI Resizable Ghost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have jQuery UI draggable working and with ghost set to true, a transparent ghost appears when I resize the element.

```
$('.container').resizable({
    ghost: true
});
```

I want to remove the background-color, set the opacity and style the border on the ghost.

```
.ui-resizable-ghost {
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 1px dashed blue !important;
    background-color: none !important;
}
```

Only the z-index and border properties seem to be taking effect though, even when I use !important.

Comment: Most of the plugin styles are programatically updated to the elements which overrides everything.

Comment: I see. So I'll have to edit the core jQuery UI js file?

Comment: Could you provide an example please? I suck at JS :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems very doable and without needing to modify the source code. Target the `.ui-resizable-helper` selector:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wLtmB/3/)**

```
.ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 4px dashed #faa;
    background-color: #eeeecc;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

To make the helper/ghost's background transparent, add:

```
.ui-resizable-ghost {
     opacity:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help mate. I think the problem si that it's pulling the background color from the child div? How do i get around that? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wLtmB/1/

Comment: When you set the background color to none on .ui-resizable-helper,  the helper window clones the resizable div including the background color, but with a lower opacity. You can just specify the new color you want in the CSS for .ui-resizable-helper.

Comment: I don't want a background-color though. I want the background to be left at none. I've tried background: transparent but that doesn't work.

Comment: It's the most beautiful thing I've ever seen :)